# How to get static map with multipolygon as an Image in python

Tags: python, gis

I am looking for way (maybe through an external API) to represent many polygons in an static map. The idea is giving the coordinates to that service,and that service or API must give an static map asn a png image with those polygons. Just like this:

[image: static map]

How to get that static map with multi polygon as an Image in python?
I am using django but any way to do it with python will do.
The service must be FREE

Comment: *The service must be FREE* raises many questions: Do you ask for a recommendation for an online service or for Python code generating the image with the polygons? If you ask for Python code: **What** do you start with? Do you start with an image of the map? Do you know the GPS coordinates of the image sides to position the multipolygons in the image at the right pixel positions (this question assumes that the provided coordinates define the polygons)?

Comment: I am looking for a python code, giving the coordeates of a polygon, or many polygons. I need to represent those coordenates as a map and get that map as an Image
polygon1_coords = [[-86.109286248,11.946898956],
    [-86.109159886,11.947196373],
    [-86.108962101,11.947092456],
    [-86.10886504,11.946897164],
    [-86.109286248,11.946898956]]

Comment: So what is your question? How to draw a polygon on an image using PIL? But then this has then nothing to do with a map or django or gis as such.

Comment: Yes I need to draw a polygon on a map. Giving the coordinates of some polygons. I need to draw those polygons over a Tile layer and adjust the bounding box, or zoom level of that map

Comment: What do you mean with *map*? Drawing requires an image, so first you have to get an appropriate image object with the RGB pixel data as e.g. PIL image in order to draw upon. I suggest you provide your best attempt on writing actual Python code - this will clarify where you map image comes from and what is known about the GPS coordinates of the image sides (or in other words the GPS-coordinates of the upper and lower corner pixel/points of the image showing the map).

Comment: Or is you question how to get an image from a Google-Maps or other map-service-site showing a defined range of GPS-coordinates? This would be then a question about an interface to the internet-map-service and not a Python programming question.

Comment: In other words ... it would be hard to help you if you don't provide any own coding attempt telling what is not working as you expect. There are services on web able to show lines connecting GPS points on maps (showing the path of your run or bike training) you could then feed with GPS-data to show the polygons. In this case you need only to generate an appropriate GPX file with the GPS-data ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format ).

Comment: What exactly do you expect the PYTHON code to do? What is your final goal is clear, but to start programming you need details. Or do you expect someone provides you with an in Python from scratch written application which does the entire job including getting the map image from Internet and creating an image with the polygons if you feed it with the polygon GPS-coordinates? Stackoverflow is usually not a free programming service you feed with the specification of the application you want the code of.

Comment: Check this : http://darribas.org/gds15/content/labs/lab_03.html

Comment: Or this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382544/draw-geojson-polygon-over-image-returned-by-mapbox-in-python